# Forcing all rows from first table of a join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have three tables, `machines` holding vending machines, `products` holding all possible products, and `machines_products` which is the intersection of the two, giving how many of each product line is stocked in a particular machine. If a product is not stocked in a machine, there is no corresponding row in the third table.

```
DESCRIBE machines_products;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| machine_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| product_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| quantity   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Each product has a category (think chocolate bars vs. drinks bottles) and a machine knows what category of products it can vend. I want a result table of all products for the category, with a quantity for a specific machine. I have got as far as this:

```
SELECT products.*, SUM(quantity) qty
FROM products
LEFT JOIN machines_products USING (product_id)
WHERE machine_id=m AND category_id=c
GROUP BY product_id;
```

The problem is that this filters out all rows where there is no quantity, whereas what I want is all rows from the left table, and NULL/0 in the `qty` column if there are no corresponding rows in the right-hand table.

BTW: this is not a homework question! I am 30 and sitting in my office :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured out the answer a short while after posting. The trick is to avoid specifying either of the columns from the third table's primary key (i.e. `machine_id` and `product_id`) in the `WHERE` clause. By using an `AND` in the `JOIN`'s `ON` condition, and specifying the machine ID there, I get the result I was looking for.

```
SELECT products.*, quantity
FROM products
LEFT JOIN machines_products
  ON products.product_id=machines_products.product_id
  AND machine_id=m
WHERE category_id=c
```

The `COALESCE()` function suggested by Brendan was not necessary in my case, since I check the value with PHP's `empty()` function, so `NULL` is fine.

As it turns out, there was never a need for `GROUP BY`, which I had been playing with when posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.*
     , SUM(mp.quantity) AS qty
FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN machine_products mp
    ON mp.product_id = p.product_id
    AND mp.machine_id = m              --- this condition moved from WHERE to ON
WHERE p.category_id = c
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, SUM(mp.quantity) AS qty 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN machines_products mp ON p.id=mp.product_id
WHERE mp.machine_id=m 
AND p.category_id=c 
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` returns `NULL` if a single value in the equation is NULL. `COALESCE` the value first and then `SUM`:

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(COALESCE(mp.quantity, 0)) AS qty
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN machine_products mp ON mp.product_id = p.id
WHERE mp.machine_id = m
AND p.category_id = c
GROUP BY p.id
```

I assumed you have a column in `products` called `id`. Rename if it's something different...