# Query for getting rows on join when one table has no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've some problem with my SQL query. Please advise. Any help is appreciated!

```
 CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
    Id  BIGINT,
    Name    VARCHAR(100),
    Amount  DECIMAL
)

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(
    Id  BIGINT,
    Name    VARCHAR(100),
    Amount  DECIMAL
)

        INSERT INTO #Table1
        SELECT Id, Name, ISNULL(dt.Amount, 0.00)
        FROM ConfigTable ct
        LEFT JOIN DataTable1 dt
        ON ct.Id = dt.ConfigId

        INSERT INTO #Table2
        SELECT Id, Name, ISNULL(dt.Amount, 0.00)
        FROM ConfigTable ct
        LEFT JOIN DataTable2 dt
        ON ct.Id = dt.ConfigId


        SELECT SUM(ISNULL(A.DataTable1Amount1, 0.0)) AS DataTable1Amount1,
               SUM(ISNULL(A.DataTable2Amount1, 0.0)) AS DataTable2Amount1,
               SUM(ISNULL(A.DataTable1Amount2, 0.0)) AS DataTable1Amount2,
               SUM(ISNULL(A.DataTable2Amount2, 0.0)) AS DataTable2Amount2,
               SUM(ISNULL(A.DataTable1Amount3, 0.0)) AS DataTable1Amount3,
               SUM(ISNULL(A.DataTable2Amount3, 0.0)) AS DataTable2Amount3
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CASE t1.Name WHEN 'ConfigName 1' THEN t1.Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS DataTable1Amount1,
               CASE t1.Name WHEN 'ConfigName 2' THEN t1.Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS DataTable1Amount2,
               CASE t1.Name WHEN 'ConfigName 3' THEN t1.Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS DataTable1Amount3,
               CASE t2.Name WHEN 'ConfigName 1' THEN t2.Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS DataTable2Amount1,
               CASE t2.Name WHEN 'ConfigName 2' THEN t2.Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS DataTable2Amount2,
               CASE t2.Name WHEN 'ConfigName 3' THEN t2.Amount ELSE 0.00 END AS DataTable2Amount3
            FROM  #Table1 t1, #Table2 t2
            WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id
        )A
```

Sample data:

Config table is a static table with following data:

```
Id, Name
1, ConfigName 1
2, ConfigName 2
3, ConfigName 3
```

DataTable1 may or may not have rows corresponding to Config table Id. If it has rows, then data will be in following format:

```
DataTable1Id, ConfigId, Amount
1, 1, 10
2, 2, 20
```

DataTable2 too may or may not have rows corresponding to Config table Id. If it has rows, then data will be in following format:

```
DataTable2Id, ConfigId, Amount
1, 1, 10
2, 2, 20
```

For the above case, expected output will be only 1 row returning all amounts.

```
DataTable1Amount1, DataTable2Amount1, DataTable1Amount2, DataTable2Amount2, DataTable1Amount3, DataTable2Amount3
10, 20, 0, 10, 20, 0
```

But if DataTable1 or DataTable2 doesn't have any rows corresponding to `ConfigId`, then the final output should show amount as 0.

```
DataTable1Id, ConfigId, Amount
No rows

DataTable2Id, ConfigId, Amount
1, 1, 10
2, 2, 20
```

Expected output:

```
DataTable1Amount1, DataTable2Amount1, DataTable1Amount2, DataTable2Amount2, DataTable1Amount3, DataTable2Amount3
0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 0
```

Current output:

```
DataTable1Amount1, DataTable2Amount1, DataTable1Amount2, DataTable2Amount2, DataTable1Amount3, DataTable2Amount3
```

No row is returned.

If I need to be more specific, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by moving the filter condition in the query **from WHERE clause to ON**. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609059/forcing-all-rows-from-first-table-of-a-join) post!

I was looking at the joins and didn't post the filters in my sample query. But the actual problem was when I use filter from the second table in WHERE clause, it returns no rows Vs when I use filter on the second data on Join's ON, all rows form first table will be returned.

```
Old query:

SELECT Id, Name, ISNULL(dt.Amount, 0.00)
        FROM ConfigTable ct
        LEFT JOIN DataTable1 dt
        ON ct.Id = dt.ConfigId
**WHERE dt.FilterColumn = c**

New query:

SELECT Id, Name, ISNULL(dt.Amount, 0.00)
        FROM ConfigTable ct
        LEFT JOIN DataTable1 dt
        ON ct.Id = dt.ConfigId **AND dt.FilterColumn = c**
```